# Exception with SpringJPA native query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

When I am trying to execute my `native query`, I am facing following exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'f,
>   codigoleyenda cl, tipocomprobante tc, moneda m, cliente c, tipotaxigv
>   ttig, t' at line 1

and my repository is as follows-

```
@Repository
public interface FacturaRepository extends JpaRepository<Factura, Integer>, CrudRepository<Factura, Integer>{
    @Query(value="select " + 
            "f.facId," + 
            "facBaja," + 
            "f.facEnvioSunat," + 
            "f.facEnvioServidor," + 
            "f.facEstadoEnvioCorreo," + 
            "f.facFechaRespuesta," + 
            "f.facRuta," + 
            "f.facSubTotal," + 
            "f.facInafecta," + 
            "f.facExonerada," + 
            "f.facGratuita," + 
            "f.facGravada," + 
            "f.facPercepcion," + 
            "f.facOtrosTributos," + 
            "f.facDescuento," + 
            "cl.codLeyCodigo," + 
            "f.facLeyenda," + 
            "f.facDetraccion," + 
            "f.facNroSerie," + 
            "f.facNroCorrelativo," + 
            "f.facFechaEmision," + 
            "tc.tipComCodigo,"+ 
            "m.monCodigo,"+  
            "ub.ubiDepartamento," + 
            "ub.ubiProvincia," + 
            "ub.ubiDistrito," + 
            "ub.ubiCodigo," + 
            "p.parRuta," + 
            "s.sucDireccionFiscal," + 
            "s.sucRuc," + 
            "s.sucTipoDocumento," + 
            "s.sucPais," + 
            "s.sucRazonSocial," + 
            "c.cliCondicionDomicilio," + 
            "c.cliDireccionFiscal," + 
            "c.cliEstado," + 
            "c.cliNumeroDocumento," + 
            "c.cliRazonSocial," + 
            "td.tipDocCodigo," + 
            "f.facIgv," + 
            "f.facIsc," + 
            "ttig.tipTaxIgvCodigo," + 
            "ttis.tipTaxIscCodigo," + 
            "f.facOtrosConceptos," + 
            "oc.otrConCodigo," + 
            "f.facTaxIgvPorcentaje," + 
            "f.facTaxIscPorcentaje," + 
            "f.facHashcode," + 
            "f.facNombreZip," + 
            "f.facTotal," + 
            "f.facRetencion," + 
            "f.facPlaca" + 
            "from factura f, codigoleyenda cl, tipocomprobante tc, moneda m, cliente c, tipotaxigv ttig, tipotaxisc ttis, otrosconceptos oc," + 
            "tipodocumento td, sucursal s, ubigeo ub, parametros p" + 
            "where c.tipDocId = td.tipDocId and  f.sucId=s.sucId and s.ubiId=ub.ubiId and s.parId=p.parId" + 
            "and f.codLeyId=cl.codLeyId and f.tipComId=tc.tipComId  and f.monId=m.monId and f.cliId=c.cliId and " + 
            "f.tipTaxIgvId=ttig.tipTaxIgvId and f.tipTaxIscId=ttis.tipTaxIscId and f.OtrConId=oc.otrConId and f.facId=?1", nativeQuery=true)
            FacturaXmlDto getFacturaXml(int facId);
```

this query is working fine with mysql, but facing the exception with `SpringJPA` and I need help on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this type of question, you would need to give out the exception.  But from just looking at it, check your spaces. You definitely need to add a space before the closing quote on the following lines:

```
"f.facPlaca" +
"tipodocumento td, sucursal s, ubigeo ub, parametros p" + 
"where c.tipDocId = td.tipDocId and  f.sucId=s.sucId and s.ubiId=ub.ubiId and s.parId=p.parId" +
```

without the space, the last word on that line runs into the first word on the next line.  Also, in your code, you might want to println the resulting query, and copy and paste that query to your database browser, and see what happens.

Comment: thank you, I already have the query correctly but I still have an error, apparently jpa can not pass the data to an object that is not my entity